# About create single column index on SQL Server for various of queries

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Lets assume a table like this

```
[KEY] [int] NOT NULL,
[INT1] [int] NULL,
[INT2] [int] NULL,
[INT3] [int] NULL,
[STR1] [varchar](20) NULL,
[STR2] [varchar](20) NULL,
[STR3] [varchar](20) NULL,
```

The query is very flexed but always like this format:
`SELECT KEY FROM [TABLE] WHERE...`

The search condition few times on single column, and most time on several columns, for `[int]` type, quesy as `BETWEEN` or `>=` or `<=`, for `varchar`, always query as `=` or `IN []`. All conditions connect with `AND`

Since the query is not always fixed on same column(s), so I wonder, if I create `INDEX` on every single column, will it increase performance, or just waste at all.

Comment: If you plan to create many single column indexes, then, it's very likely that they will be non-covering [non-clustered] indexes. Kimberly Tripp has an interesting article regarding non-covering NC indexes and [the tipping point](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't just create an index on every single column - that's a total waste of time and resources!

Basically, my approach is always:

1. define a **good** primary and clustering key on any "normal" table (except for e.g. staging tables etc.) - that's a big step already
2. put non-clustered indices on any foreign key columns - those really help a lot, especially with JOIN's

And that's it!

**Then:**

- observe your system - see when things are slow
- measure system performance
- capture a server-side trace to get a representative workload
- analyse that workload, and see what additional indices might be helpful
- do tweaks - one at a time
- measure again and again to see if you've improved system performance (or not)

You need a full, representative workload to see what queries are really common and used a lot - and see what indices might be beneficial for those frequent queries. Otherwise, you might be providing index help for all the wrong queries, and you might actually slow things down ...

You'd be surprised just how rarely non-clustered indices will really help!

Don't **over-index** - it's just as bad - if not worse - than having no indices at all ! It might be worse, because every index that you have will also need to be **maintained** over its lifetime... and there ain't no free lunch - not even here...

See Kimberly Tripp's excellent blog post [Indexes: just because you can doesn't mean you should!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Indexes_JustBecauseUCan_NO.aspx) on the topic - very helpful, lots of insights. Or basically, [just read anything Kim has blogged on indexes](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/category/indexes.aspx) - she's the *Queen of Indexing* and anything she's posted on her blog is usually extremely helpful and beneficial!

Furthermore, SQL Server 2005 and newer offer DMV's (Dynamic Management Views) that allow you to find out what indices are not being used (those can be removed) or which are missing, according to SQL Server's query optimizer's opinion. See [SQL Server - Find missing and unused indexes](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2009/04/08/SQL-Server---Find-missing-and-unused-indexes.aspx) for more details. But be aware: those are **dynamic** views - they're reset with each system start and might not be totally accurate - don't just do everything they tell you - take everything with a grain of salt and consider carefully what you do - document it, so that you can undo it, if things get worse rather than better!

Answer (score 2):

Creating an index on every column could affect the performance, as said in the [General Index Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191195%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Large numbers of indexes on a table affect the performance of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and MERGE statements because all indexes must be adjusted appropriately as data in the table changes.

Also, if you want to always retrieve the `KEY` column in your queries, consider adding it as an *included column* in the index, so it can be retrieved only accessing the index, avoiding access to the table. But bear in mind, creating an index with included columns it's available since SQL Server 2005, and later versions.

You can examine what are the most frequent filter combinations, and only add a few *multicolumn* indexes, keeping in mind:

> Consider the order of the columns if the index will contain multiple
>   columns. The column that is used in the WHERE clause in an equal to
>   (=), greater than (>), less than (<), or BETWEEN search condition, or
>   participates in a join, should be placed first. Additional columns
>   should be ordered based on their level of distinctness, that is, from
>   the most distinct to the least distinct.

Comment: "affect the performance", means slow it down on (`INSERT, UPDATE...`), right? But will make `SELECT` faster, is that is?

Comment: Yes, that's it. That will improve the performances on queries that do not modify data.

Comment: @Chopin: How should I interpret third paragraph: _"if you want to always retrieve the KEY column in your queries, consider adding it as an included column in the index, so it can be retrieved only accessing the index, avoiding access to the table"_? For ex., should I include into index the primary key columns using `INCLUDE ...` clause when the table is heap ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean If your table is a heap, and you have a primary key defined, then I guess you have it defined as a nonclustered index. If you define another nonclustered index on other columns, whether you should include the PK columns or not varies upon if they form part of the projection in the queries using this new index (and also, of course, if you need to gain performance on these queries). That answers your question?

Comment: @Chopin: My question is about the interpretation of quoted paragraph. First, it refers only to `key` column(s). Second, isn't clear if  `key` column(s) should be interpreted from logical point of view (primary key, unique key) or from physical point of view (`key` column(s) from other indexes).

Comment: @BogdanSahlean: Actually, I was referring to the column named `KEY` in the table the OP posted (`[KEY] [int] NOT NULL`). I didn't assume that column being a primary key, just a column that always has to be retrieved when the index is accessed (as the OP said, the queries would be in the form `SELECT KEY FROM [TABLE] WHERE...`).

Comment: @Chopin: It makes more sense now this answer. I will give you my vote but you should mention that `INCLUDE` clause (for creating indexes) was introduced by `SQL Server 2005`.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean: thanks for point that out, I'll _include_ it in my answer :)

Comment: @Chopin: [You guys still use SQL Server 2000? Really?](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/You-guys-still-use-SQL-Server-2000-Really.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Putting the indexes in will help queries partly if it leads directly to the correct result, but also can give great benefits if it improves locality of reference and reduces the amount of memory read.

For the question as asked, the answer is "it depends". It depends on your queries. If there is one major column queried, which always appears in the search, e.g. `INT1`, create an index on:

```
 unique (INT1, INT2, INT3, REF)
```

Then any query referencing INT1 and any combination of the other fields will be quick.

Also, any query referencing INT2 but not INt1 will also benefit because the whole table doesn't need to be read - only the index. Even though INT2 is not at the head of the index, the query still benefits: the DB will skip over INT1 and just look at INT2, but it can get a view of the table INT2 values, without having to read the whole table.

So really you need to better understand the queries which will be done. If one column ALWAYS appears, put that at the head of an index. If another column OFTEN appears, that should be number 2.

If there are two columns which both often appear, you can do this:

```
unique (INT1, INT2, INT3, REF),
unique (INT2, INT1, INT3, REF)
```

Then we would hope that if INT1 is not specified, but INT2 is specified, the second index will be used.

Don't use too many indexes though, they can take up a lot of disk space.

**Bottom Line:** Test the queries with and without the indexes. You need to collect 10-20 minimum sample queries, and test their IO and clock times. That is the only way to get a true answer.

Comment: Can I say your suggest is, create 1 index on [[INT1],[INT2],[INT3],[STR1],[STR2],[STR3]], which not include [Key] (the order of the column depends on how often it queries)

Comment: No, not really. My suggestion is to 1) get a sample of actual queries and work out which columns are used most frequently to inform your decision and 2) test it to make sure it works. You **should** include `KEY` in the index though as this is the data you want - this will save the need to read the main table.

Comment: Just to remark, when @Ben says _"You should include `KEY` in the index"_, he means including it as an [included column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but not as part of the index key.